# Upgrading to Struts 2.3.20 and jCaptcha 1.0

Tags: struts2, jcaptcha

The project uses jCaptcha 1.0, after upgrading from 2.3.16 to Struts 2.3.20 the application could not start. 
Our project is not using jCaptcha struts integration, so we do not have and jCaptcha configuration ins strust.xml or web.xml, for instance we do **NOT** have below line in struts.xml

```
<plug-in className="com.octo.captcha.module.struts.CaptchaServicePlugin"/>
```

I think some plugin management mechanism is changed so the struts 2.3.20 try to find and start this plugin while 2.3.16 didn't.

The error is as below:

```
ERROR finder.ClassFinder             Unable to read class [com.octo.captcha.module.struts.image.RenderImageCaptchaAction]
Could not load org/apache/struts/action/Action.class - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.readClassDef(ClassFinder.java:723)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.access$400(ClassFinder.java:71)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder$InfoBuildingClassVisitor.extractSuperInterfaces(ClassFinder.java:770)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder$InfoBuildingClassVisitor.visit(ClassFinder.java:757)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.readClassDef(ClassFinder.java:718)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.<init>(ClassFinder.java:113)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.findActions(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:347)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:274)
ERROR finder.ClassFinder             Unable to read class [com.octo.captcha.module.struts.VerifyCaptchaChallengeAction]
Could not load org/apache/struts/action/Action.class - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.readClassDef(ClassFinder.java:723)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.access$400(ClassFinder.java:71)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder$InfoBuildingClassVisitor.extractSuperInterfaces(ClassFinder.java:770)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder$InfoBuildingClassVisitor.visit(ClassFinder.java:757)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.readClassDef(ClassFinder.java:718)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.<init>(ClassFinder.java:113)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.findActions(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:347)
ERROR finder.ClassFinder             Error loading class [com.octo.captcha.module.struts.CaptchaServicePlugin]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts/action/PlugIn
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassLoaderInterfaceDelegate.loadClass(ClassLoaderInterfaceDelegate.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder$ClassInfo.get(ClassFinder.java:563)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder$3.test(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:613)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder$3.test(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:600)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.findClasses(ClassFinder.java:343)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.findActions(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:393)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:347)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:274)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:435)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:479)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts.action.PlugIn
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 35 more
ERROR finder.ClassFinder             Error loading class [com.octo.captcha.module.struts.image.RenderImageCaptchaAction]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts/action/Action
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassLoaderInterfaceDelegate.loadClass(ClassLoaderInterfaceDelegate.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder$ClassInfo.get(ClassFinder.java:563)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.findClasses(ClassFinder.java:344)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.findActions(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:393)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts.action.Action
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 33 more
ERROR finder.ClassFinder             Error loading class [com.octo.captcha.module.struts.VerifyCaptchaChallengeAction]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts/action/Action
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassLoaderInterfaceDelegate.loadClass(ClassLoaderInterfaceDelegate.java:34)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder$ClassInfo.get(ClassFinder.java:563)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.findClasses(ClassFinder.java:344)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.findActions(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:393)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:347)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:274)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:967)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts.action.Action
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 33 more
ERROR finder.ClassFinder             Error loading class [com.octo.captcha.module.struts.VerifyCaptchaChallengeMethodAction]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts/action/Action
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts.action.Action
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: These not found classes `org/apache/struts/action/...` are from S1.

Comment: I know but why I see this error after update ?! Why didn't this error happens on version 2.3.16.3 ?!

Comment: Check project dependencies. Check your code for `com.octo.captcha.module.struts` classes.